# Using tensorboard to view directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm trying to use tensorboard tool to show our directed graph. Indeed, I would like to make some modifications so that the graph will show our specific labels on the edge and the arrow can be shown on all kinds of edges (not only reference edge by default). Since the graph of tensorboard is drawn by JavaScript (using D3 libraries) in tf-tensorboard.html file. I have made some changes in this file (i.e., tf-tensorboard.html) and succeeded in modifying the lengths of edges between the scopes and operations, but can't show the arrow at the end of the edge.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you please describe in more detail what changes you made to `tf-tensorboard.html` and perhaps include an image of the problem with the visualization?

Comment: Thank you mrry for your message! I have solved my problem. Actually, what I have made some changes in the following functions: getLableForEdge (to change the label of the edge) and appendEdge (to change the path.style). It now shows our own label and arrow.